# What is the value of epsilon?

Tags: java, epsilon

Is the value of epsilon in java always the same?

In my lesson in my online class it says

```
double x = 0.7, y = 1.0 - 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.1; 
System.out.println("x is " + (x)); 
System.out.println("y is " + (y)); 
System.out.println("x == y is " + (x == y)); 
final double EPSILON = 1.0E-6; 
System.out.println("Math.abs(x - y) < EPSILON is " + (Math.abs(x - y) < EPSILON));
```

which yields

```
x is 0.7
y is 0.7000000000000001
x == y is false
Math.abs(x - y) < EPSILON is true
```

So I was just wondering is epsilon always 1.0E-6 or can it be anything?

Comment: This isnt java question. :) Epsilon value is not fixed. Its notation used in arbitrary expressions, usually for very small values. [Ref- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176783 ]
Correct place to ask this question is https://math.stackexchange.com. Happy learning.

Comment: It can be anything you want. It's your decision to what precision two `double`s shall be considered equal. It depends on your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just defined it as one millionth. It could be anything that (a) is useful to you, and (b) is representable in the chosen format.

The magnitude of your chosen epsilon depends on the magnitude of the values you're working with; it represents your view of what 'close enough' means, and close enough for numbers near 1 is not the same as close enough for numbers near 1000000000000000 nor near 0.000000000000001.